# Is there a way to show all Current Task data in an email?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am curious to know if there is a way that I can show all `[%Current Task:*%]` data. I know i can go through and add one at a time to the message

```
[%Current Task:One%]
[%Current Task:Two%]
[%Current Task:Three%]
```

What I want to know is there a way to list them all out?
If anyone is familiar with jQuery, there is a function called `JSON.stringify(Object)` that will list out all the properties instead of going through one at a time to display values. Is there a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all the properties (Columns) of the Tasks list you can use REST API or JSOM to fetch the data from the list on the Client-side.

REST example:

('listname') /Items

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

JSOM example:

http://www.thesharepointguide.com/sharepoint-javascript/

Sharepoint JavaScript References

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594.aspx

Comment: Hi, I know i can do all of this on the front end but my questions is asking if this is possible through the workflow.

Comment: Here is the example for **CALLING THE SHAREPOINT 2013 REST API FROM A SHAREPOINT DESIGNER WORKFLOW**

Comment: [Link](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Comment: you like caps lock and bold font?